# Read xml file attributes within two elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml file and I am trying to get the attribute value which is inside two elements.

XML:

```
<Var>
  <Sour>
    <Processing>
      <Interpolation method="akimaspline"/>
      <Aggregation method="summation" />
    </Processing>
  </Sour>
</Var >
```

C#:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFile);
XmlNodeList elemNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName(Aggregation );
for (int y = 0; y < elemNode.Count; y++)
    result = elemNode[y].Attributes[method].Value;
```

The following code return an empty string instead of summation.

Comment: You are re-assigning 'result' variable on each loop iteration. What   values 'Aggregation' and 'method' variables have? Can you use LINQ?

Comment: Well, I cannot find Aggregation tag and LINQ would be great, but I am not an expert in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) approach - get all elements under root (gives you both Aggregation and Interpolation) and get 'method' attribute values from each element:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var methods = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                  .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("method"))
                  .Distinct();
```

Output:

```
[ "summation", "linear" ]
```

Getting values separately:

```
var aggregationMethod = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("Aggregation").Attribute("method");
```

---

UPDATE: After you have changed xml, `Processing` is not root of your file anymore. You have several options now - just select all elements manually from root

```
var method = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("Sour")
                         .Element("Processing")
                         .Element("Aggregation").Attribute("method");
```

You can use `Descendants` to find `Aggregation` element without specifying path

```
var method = (string)xdoc.Descendants("Aggregation").First().Attribute("method");
```

Or you can use XPath to specify full or relative path to 'Aggregation' element:

```
var method = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//Aggregation").Attribute("method");
```

Comment: But I want get For tag Aggregation only summation and for tag Interpolation  only linear.

Comment: @doro can you please explain what do you mean by getting only summation for Aggregation? You want to get these values separately?

Comment: Ok, if I search for tag Aggregation, I need back summation.  If I search for tag Interpolation, I need back linear.

Comment: @doro updated answer - just provide element name and get its attribute value

Comment: I don't know why I get this exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @doro make sure you are passing element name which exists in xml. Otherwise you need to do null-check

Comment: I see, so in the example works but in my file which is bigger doesn't.

Comment: I just changed the xml file. Please let me know.

Comment: @doro updated answer. Please use your real xml/code next time :)

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry, I didn't know that would make such difference! :-)